# How do I create a multiple sheets that use a google sheet named TOTAL as the data source?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

How do I create multiple sheets that use a Google sheet named `TOTAL` as the data source?  Each sheet must contain the same three columns from `TOTAL` and other specific data, for instance, `FLUX` will have six columns, three from `TOTAL` and three custom columns added manually.

I used a query function to import the data from `TOTAL` to `FLUX` so that updating data in `TOTAL` will update it also in `FLUX`

The data in `TOTAL` are not fixed. It will change adding rows, which might change the order of the list. For instance, adding the row 13 in `TOTAL` will shift down the data in column A:C in `FLUX`, but not columns D:F

Is that a way to keep the reference out of the `QUERY` part?

Here an example: [Click me](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZgkV8hD-us224VJOvOuVGdZduWz4qHjJU4AshC2H5kk/edit#gid=1347407055)

Answer (score 0):

you would need to create ID system and then you would be able to match your query with rest of the static columns. in sheet `SALES` remove that query and put IDs in A column. then your query will be:

```
=QUERY(TOTAL!A1:D, "SELECT A, B, C, D WHERE C is not null", 1)
```

where column A contains IDs and then you create new sheet `SHEET3` and paste this query in A1

and this formula in E1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A, SALES!A1:G, {4,5,6}, 0), ))
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem and I can't understand few steps from the answer.
Firstly, the A columns of both sheets (TOTAL and SALES) must have IDs?
Secondly, I can't really understand how the Sheets SALES should look like. Should it be like, Col A = IDs, ColB to C query from TOTAL and Col E to G static data?
In this case is it still correct creating a query in Sheet3 reading data from TOTAL?
Thank

Comment: This is not an answer for the original question. Consider creating a new question or waiting for this question to be answered.

Comment: I suggest you remove your answer as you can receive downvotes.